# ios launching login from appdelegate and pushing a uitabbarcontroller from login

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have set the first view in my AppDelegate as the root controller...which is a login screen.  When the login button is pressed, I'm pushing a UITabBarController with all the views.  Problems I'm having is 1)I can't seem to get rid of the back button, 2)I can't add any nav bar buttons on the views after they are pushed, but the dummy texts on the views show up and 3)Cannot set the title of the views.  Basically, right now I can't modify the nav bar.  Here's what I have:

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
LogInViewController *login = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *loginNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:login];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = loginNav;
[self.window addSubview:loginNav.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

That part works fine.  Now LoginViewController.m:

```
//button from nav bar is pressed and I create the tabbar
- (void)push:(id)sender{
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *tabItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:4];

View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *view1Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
view1Nav.tabBarItem.title = @"View1";
view1Nav.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; //<--doesn't get set from here either
[tabItems addObject:view1Nav];

View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *view2Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view2];
[tabItems addObject:view2Nav];

View3 *view3 = [[View3 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *view3Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view3];
[tabItems addObject:view3Nav];

View4 *view4 = [[View4 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *view4Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view4];
[tabItems addObject:view4Nav];

tabBarController.viewControllers = tabItems;
tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;//doesn't work either...
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

I tried setting the titles here and even turning off the back button from the login controller but doesn't work.  The tab bar views now are basically blank.

View1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 50, 30)];
[l setText:@"something"];
[l setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
[l setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:l];
//the label is on the screen but the following doesn't work
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Blah"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(something:)];
//the nav bar is empty besides the back button which I tried turning off every way:
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
//or
[self.navigationItem hidesBackButton]
//or even hide the entire bar...anyway, nothing works
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is it possible to do everything programmatically like I'm trying to do?

Comment: So you have a tab bar controller in a nav controller, with 4 tabs that are also nav controllers, correct?

Comment: @michaels Yes, that's correct.  The LoginViewController is a nav controller, from which I'm pushing the tab bar controller with 4 tabs which are also nav controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about doing everything programmatically. But it would invite more human-error mistakes I think. Anyway let's get to the problem.

You should definitely remove below line from your code. It is totally wrong. You are adding another redundant view to your window.

```
[self.window addSubview:loginNav.view];
```

And it is better to replace below line:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

with this (by doing so, you will remove your login page from the navigation stack and the back button would not be a problem anymore):

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[tabBarController] animated:YES];
```

Once you accomplished above, you should give your results. I think that would be enough. Rest of your code seems OK.

EDIT: You can try below code (i was able to use it in a project).

```
View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *view1Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
view1.tabBarItem.title = @"View1";
view1Nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[view1.view addSubview:view1Nav.view];
[tabItems addObject:view1];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  The warning I'm getting is setViewControllers needs an array, and tabBarController is an UITabBarController.  I tried using the array of view controllers and it crashed giving me "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!'"

Comment: That worked!  No back button.  Now is it possible to set the title and the nav bar buttons?  Or should I just get rid of the navigation controllers in the tab bar and add a custom tab bar?  Because it still wll not let me add a title or nav bar buttons...

Comment: I updated my answer. Please inform us about the results.

Comment: Changing to that, the nav bar in view1 is still blank.  I tried adding self.navigationItem.title = @"view1"; but it's still blank...and also the tabBarItem.title the title disappeared

Comment: Because we set `view1.navigationBarHidden` to `YES`, the nav bar you are seeing is the outer navigation controller's nav bar (namely `loginNav`). You should hide it and show navigation bars four each inner navigation controller.

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is it's not actually hiding the nav bar from loginNav.  I created a navbar in view1 and tried adding it as a subview and also inserting it above self.navigationController.navigationBar.  I can see the black created nav bar in the background...

Comment: You do not need to add an other navbar, you have plenty of navigation controllers :)

Comment: So I don't understand...how do I add a title and buttons to the navigation bar?  Setting view1.navigationBarHidden to YES doesn't actually hide it...it's still there...

Comment: I think you are seeing the `loginNav`s navigation bar.

Comment: You can hide it when navigating your tab bar controller.

Comment: Hmmm...I think we went as far as we can.  I can't get it to work.  I think I need to restructure my logic.  Maybe I will make my tabbar controller the root and on top of it (learn to use custom containers) use custom containers to display the login view...

Comment: I'm an idiot...it just hit me this morning.  The loginNav is showing, not the inidividual ones from the tab bar views!!!  Just hiding the loginNav worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the back button, you should use `backBarButtonItem` instead of `leftBarButtonItem`, or call `hidesBackButton` on the Tab Controller's navigation item, rather than in your custom views since the tab controller is a direct descendant of the navigation controller.

As far as the titles go, I don't think having nested navigation controllers is supported in iOS - i.e. you can only have one navigation bar at a time, and in the scenario you proposed, that would be the navigation bar of the highest-level navigation controller. Do you really need nested navigation controllers? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Still doesn't work wherever I set the backBarButtonItem.  I'll rethink my structure if I can't get this to work. ismailgulek got it to work without a nav bar with his edit.  Now I need to figure out how to set the title and buttons on the tab views